# Loading xslx file causes "NoneType object not iterable" error

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

I want to read xlsx file but i am getting error
My code :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'F:\123.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    wb = load_workbook(filename = '123.xlsx', use_iterators=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 202, in load_workbook
    parsed_styles = read_style_table(archive)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 181, in read_style_table
    p.parse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 53, in parse
    self.parse_named_styles()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 109, in parse_named_styles
    names = self._parse_style_names()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.3.0b1-py2.7.egg\openpyxl\reader\style.py", line 128, in _parse_style_names
    for _name in node:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

how it can be solved?

Comment: Even I am getting this error any ideas how to solve it ?

Comment: This works perfectly on linux. Still no solution for windows

Comment: I am getting this error on Mac , Linux and Windows it has something to do with the excel itself , currently the xm/stlye.xml is missing the cellStyle entry hence the error came.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in openpyxml library, fortunately it was fixed and your issue can be solved by upgrading to 2.3.1 or newer. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35669067/170918

Comment: Thank you. I will try :)